# NSManagedObject fault / cannot get 'primitive' object handled by NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

I am struggling with CoreData. I'd like to fetch the following object:

```
@interface Email : NSManagedObject {
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *contact;
@end
```

..and put the result inside a NSMutableArray, but the NSString contents, (not NSManagedObjects!). This is because I am using json-framework and that engine does not allow NSManagedObjects to be passed.

These lines fetch perfom the fetch from CoreData

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Emails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *fetchedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    fetchedObjects= [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    flight.emails=fetchedObjects;
```

The 'flight' object is declared as follows:

```
@interface Flight : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray                  *_emails;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSMutableArray   *emails;
```

With this code I am getting CoreData faults. I tried some other implementation variants, but never actually managed to have NSString objects in flight.emails, but always NSManagedObjects. What I tried was to implement a dedicated getter function in the Email NSManagedObject that copies the fetched NSString and returns the copy.

I get the idea that this is kind of a common problem, however, my research has not led to a solution on this one here.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, `setPropertiesToFetch:` only works when requesting the returned objects be dictionaries. So a couple of problems in your code:

1. You are asking for specific property (email), but have not set the return type to dictionary. Take a look at `setResultType:`.
2. You still need to take the result and extract the email objects from it. You cannot just assign the resulting array to your emails property.

Try this:

```
[fetchedRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSArray* results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if(error != nil || results == nil) return;

flight.emails = [results valueForKeyPath:@"email"];
```

Comment: Remark: Checking for an error condition should always be done by checking the return value (in this case: `if (results == nil) ...`) and not by checking the `error` variable. (Documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Leo Natan, your answer hit it.